# How to get runtime memory consumed by all the objects individually on heap in java

Tags: java, memory, profiling

I am currently running the following code, which shows that my java application is using nearly 5mb of memory. But my mac's activity monitor says its using 185 mb. Where is the extra memory used? Also my memory consumed is constantly increasing starting from 5 mb rising to 7 mb in a min even when my app is idle.

Also is there any java class which lets me observe the latest objects (all objects separately) on heap and there memory consumption during runtime?

```
  package profiling;

    public class MemConsumption {


        public static void profiling() {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
            System.out.println("Used memory is bytes: " + memory);
            System.out.println("Used memory is megabytes: "
                    + bytesToMegabytes(memory));

        }

        public static long bytesToMegabytes(long bytes) {
                final long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;//1024 kb of 1024 bytes

            return bytes / MEGABYTE;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

> I am currently running the following code, which shows that my java application is using nearly 5mb of memory.

This is the amount of hep allocated, the actual amount used by objects is likely to be smaller.

If you want more accurate accounting you can use `-XX:-UseTLAB` and you will see to the byte how much is used.  Note: the is much slower for a multi-threaded application, but much more accurate.

> But my mac's activity monitor says its using 185 mb. Where is the extra memory used?

Most likely it is showing you how much *virtual memory* you are using which includes the maximum heap size (the address space for the heap is reserved on startup) and shared libraries, thread stacks, perm gen, direct memory, memory mapped files e.g. ByteBuffer etc.

Note: the virtual memory does not represent the amount of memory which is allocated, and unique to the process.

> Also my memory consumed is constantly increasing starting from 5 mb rising to 7 mb in a min even when my app is idle.

How did you determine the heap size if you are not really doing anything?  Monitoring an application uses some heap.

> Also is there any java class which lets me observe the latest objects (all objects separately) on heap and there memory consumption during runtime?

You need to dump the heap and view it in VisualVM or a commercial profiler.

BTW MB = Mega-bytes, Mb = mega bits, mb = milli-bits

Comment: Maybe you also mention direct memory usage

Comment: I am just printing the memory used, check the line -             System.out.println("Used memory is bytes: " + memory);
, so why is my memory consumed increasing?

Comment: also when i tried dumping the data, visualvm says "cannot heap dump on my app" why?